# Ceiling function inequality mistake in an article?

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm reading a paper which states the following (I'll just write the troubling parts):

> The probability that $n < N(T)$, which we represent by $P(n<N(T))$
>   ... because $N(T) = \lceil \lambda T\rceil$ we get... 
>   $$P \Big(n < \lceil \lambda T\rceil \Big) = P(\lambda > \frac{n}{T} \Big)$$

I'm not really sure, but if I understand correctly the ceiling function,

$$n < \lceil \lambda T \rceil$$ is $$n-1 < \lambda T$$

and so

$$P(n < \lceil \lambda T \rceil) = P(n - 1 < \lambda T) = P \Big( \lambda > \frac{n-1}{T} \Big)$$

If the paper is right, do I missed something?

This is the [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2771665/pdf/jeab-92-03-423.pdf) (p. 452)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First line of p. 452 "... then $N(t)$ equals the smallest integer greater than $\lambda t$, which we represent by the symbol $\lceil \lambda t \rceil$" gives a slightly unusual definition of the "ceiling" brackets.  Normally, the ceiling of $(0,1]$ is $1$.  Here, $\lceil x \rceil$ for $x \in [0,1)$ is $1$.  (The smallest integer greater than $0$ is $1$ and the smallest integer greater than $1$ is $2$.)  When we use the ceiling brackets in this answer, we are using the paper's definition.

This means $\lambda T \in \left[ \left\lceil \lambda T \right\rceil - 1, \lceil \lambda T \rceil \right)$.  Let's write this as $\lceil \lambda T \rceil = \lambda T + \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon \in (0,1]$.  Then $n < \lceil \lambda T \rceil$ means 
$$  n < \lambda T  + \varepsilon  $$ for some $\varepsilon \in (0,1]$.  Subtracting $\varepsilon$ and dividing by $T$ (assuming $T > 0$), we have
$$  \frac{n - \varepsilon}{T} < \lambda  \text{.}  $$

This isn't *quite* $\frac{n}{T} < \lambda$.  It is an approximation with error (strictly) less than $1/T$.  Their subsequent approximations are about as precise, so this isn't an awful approximation.

Comment: Nice. But see that in Eq 2 they said «$P (n > \lceil \lambda T \rceil) = P(n - 1 > \lambda T)$», but if $\lceil \lambda T \rceil = \lambda T + \varepsilon$ then $n > \lceil \lambda T \rceil$ must be $n - \varepsilon < \lambda t$, isn't it? Seems more like an arbitrary convenience.

Comment: From $n > \lceil \lambda T \rceil$, we deduce $n - \varepsilon > \lambda T$.